# How to match emoticons with regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I need to capture smiley faces like

```
:)
:P
:-P
=)
:D
;)
```

And so on, along with general text. This is my current regex:

```
\b[0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\./()=:;]+\b
```

However, it doesn't match ()=:; for some reason. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** Based on Mark's feedback here is an example that I need to parse:

```
hi =as.) friend :) haha yay! ;) =) test test) R&R I.O.U. 24/7
```

This should extract:

```
hi
friend
:)
haha
yay
;)
=)
test
test
R&R
I.O.U.
24/7
```

I'm having trouble getting this to work using any of the solutions proposed.

Comment: Are you assuming they'll always be written left to right?

Comment: I was, but that's an interesting point I hadn't considered.

Comment: You should really make a list of all of the **valid** emoticons you want to match, and try to describe it from there.  Otherwise your regex would catch pretty much whatever garbage user types like `$#*(&$#`.

Comment: Note that most smilies will _NOT_ start and/or end on `\b` word boundaries. One good way to go is to require whitespace (or end of string) before and after the smilie using lookaround assertions. i.e. `(?<=^|\s)(?:list|of|smilies)(?=$|\s)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example that captures a word followed by the above examples.  It captures a single word and a following emoticon in separate capture groups.  The [Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/n4SzR3MK0C).

```
\s(\w+)\s((?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|D|P))
```

**Edit** Based on the edits and the given example, this *might* be what is desired.  It defines two capture groups, one for the general text and one for an emoticon.  [Here is the Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/75vWburwcM).

```
([0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/\(\)=:;]+)|((?::|;|=)(?:-)?(?:\)|D|P))
```

Comment: That one seems brittle if I have more than 2 words in a line or more than one space between words, etc.

Comment: @Wesley:  Feel free to change it to  match your   needs   ;).  The idea is to show how you might define an emoticon capture regex.  The group at the end defines the emoticon regex.  It requires one of `:;=` followed by 0 or 1 `-` (a dash) followed by 1 of `)DP`.

Comment: @Mark: I get this now, thanks. The only issue is that it doesn't address the second requirement-- that it also captures general text. I need to capture text matching `[0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/]+`

Comment: @Wesley:  It is not clear to me what you are trying to capture.  Is it that "general" text followed by an emoticon?  Or any of that general text that contains an emoticon?  Or can it be text without an emoticon as well?  It might not hurt to put into your post examples of text that should match as well as examples that should not match.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I added an example.

Comment: @Wesley:  I looked at the results a bit more closely and I'm not sure it is still quite what you are asking for.  For example, it captures the `=as.)`, which I don't think you wanted.  And offhand, I'm not quite sure what the adjustment would be for that.  Nonetheless, it is fun to think about these while waiting for compiles to finish.

Comment: @Mark: It's probably as close as we can get with a regular expression. Tokenizing english terms is impossible in the general case, but for a quick hack, this will definitely do. I'm fine with filtering out any random gibberish words that aren't in my dictionary.

Comment: @Wesley: That seems to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I'm :'( that it doesn't match `:'(`

Answer (score 1):

I tested it [here with Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/B2Pd0VmQhz). If I escape the `/` then it works. (Update: and remove the word boundaries.)

```
[0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/()=:;]+
```

Update: The forward slash escaping was the error message I got from rubular. The real problem here are the `\b` anchors. They are matching a word boundary, i.e. a boundary from `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to something else. that means it will not match a `:-)` because there is no word boundary.

Comment: I apparently don't understand at all what the OP is asking.  The above regex captures pretty much anything whether it has an emoticon or not.  It likes `ab'c&dD:ef(x&a-b( =6` for example.  Is that what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @Mark, I am also not sure and I know that this will match a lot of stuff. My solution was only to fix his "bug", that was the only thing I was able to do late at night, but you did a better job (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove \b in front of the character class and behind the character class or escape / it works.

I think the reason why it works when you remove the word boundary is because it will only match words with alphanumeric characters...if I don't remember it wrong.